# angular-datatables in a directive. Cant call function in withFnServerData()

Tags: angularjs, datatables, server-side, angular-datatables

i have a question about calling a function in a Angular directive. Below is my directive, where i want to encapsulate the code from the controller. From the controller i get the URL and the columns. dtOptions is set in the directive.

That works so far and the table appears. The problem is that the DTOptionsBuilder doesn´t call the function serverData. when i add the brackets in FnServerData(serverData()), the method is called, but the parameters are undefined. The code works when defined in the controller.

Do you see a way that works?

**Directive**

```
 angular.module('tab')
  .directive('tabledirective', tableDirective); 

  function tableDirective(DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, RESTService){


    return {
      templateUrl: '../../views/tableTemplate.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function (scope, elem, attr) {   
            var dtOption;

            function serverData(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                //All the parameters you need is in the aoData variable
                var draw = aoData[0].value;
                var order = aoData[2].value;
                var start = aoData[3].value;
                var length = aoData[4].value;
                var search = aoData[5].value;
                //Then just call your service to get the records from server side
                RESTService.get(scope.options.url, start, length, search, order, draw).success(function (result) {
                  var records = {
                      'draw': result.data.draw,
                      'recordsTotal': result.data.total,
                      'recordsFiltered': result.data.filtered,
                      'data': result.data.records
                  };
                  fnCallback(records);
               });
            };

          dtOption = DTOptionsBuilder
              .newOptions()
              .withFnServerData(serverData)
              .withBootstrap()
              .withDataProp('data')
              .withOption('processing', true)
              .withOption('serverSide', true)
              .withOption('paging', true)
              .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
              .withDisplayLength(10);  

          scope.options.dtoptions = dtOption;     
      }
    };
  }
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('tab')
 .controller('tableCtrl', tableCtrl);

function tableCtrl(DTColumnBuilder, DTOptionsBuilder, $scope){

  $scope.options = {
      dtcolumns: [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Age', 'Alter'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Adresse', 'Adresse'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('Name', 'Name')
      ],
      dtoptions: '',
      url: 'http://localhost:9000/api/Data/Get'
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the Problem. angular-datatables serves already a directive. To tell Angular to render the table inside the scope, you must append the element `<table>` to some element, which is declared in the template.

With $compile the table get rendered in the scope

```
  return {
  template: '<div></div>',
  restrict: 'E',
  link: function (scope, elem, attr) {   
        var dtOption;

        ...
      scope.options.dtoptions = dtOption;
      elem.append('<table datatables=""...</table>');
      $compile(elem.contents())(scope);

  }
 };
}
```